# Prove that $\sum_n 2^nx^n=\frac{1}{1-2x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

My text book states that:
$$\sum_n 2^nx^n=\frac{1}{1-2x}$$
However this doesn't look obvious to me and I would like to prove it, but I don't know how. Could someone help me?

*Background:* This "formula" appears in the process of finding the generating funcion of the sequence given by: $a_n=\{ \frac{2^n}{n} \}$

Comment: Do you know that$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty y^n=\frac1{1-y}\quad(|y|\lt1)$$If so just use $y=2x$ both sides.

Comment: By chance should it be $2^{-n}$?

Comment: It should be added: This formula is only true for$ |x|<1/2.$

Comment: @fdez The sum is of an infinite [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) with, assuming $n$ starts at $0$, $a = 1$ and $r = 2x$.

Comment: @MatthewEngelstein Nope. I think you're confusing $x$'s coefficient with the radius of convergence Thomas Andrews mentioned.